# Create relationship based on nodes connected to other entity

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am creating a Jazz knowledge base and am now in the process of linking jazz musicians together. I would like to create a relationship between the musicians called :PLAYED_WITH if they have ever worked on a same recording release.

I have tried to do this using the following code:

```
MATCH (a:Artist), (other:Artist)
WHERE
a.genre = 'jazz' AND
EXISTS((a)-[:INSTRUMENT]->(:Release)<-[:INSTRUMENT]-(other))
CREATE (a)-[r:PLAYED_WITH]->(other)
RETURN  count(r)
```

The query runs, but it has been executing for hours now leading me to believe it has run into an infinite loop. By the way, there are around 5,500 jazz musicians in my DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an infinite loop, but you do have a cartesian product happening here, your first MATCH will result in at least 5500 x 5500 = 30,250,000 pairs to evaluate (likely more since `other` isn't restricted to Jazz musicians), so that's a lot of pairs to check for for paths between.

First, you'll want to make sure you have an index on :Artist(genre) so your initial lookup of `a` is relatively quick.

Next, move the desired pattern between `a` and `other` up into the MATCH, so we only have to do traversal to find musicians who have played together, and avoid the cartesian product.

It may also help to get DISTINCT pairs, as it's likely if two musicians have played together that they've played together several times, so we only want to deal with each distinct pair once.

So see if this will work for you:

```
MATCH (a:Artist)-[:INSTRUMENT]->(:Release)<-[:INSTRUMENT]-(other:Artist)
WHERE a.genre = 'jazz' 
WITH DISTINCT a, other
MERGE (a)-[r:PLAYED_WITH]-(other)
RETURN  count(DISTINCT r)
```

Comment: Thank you @InverseFalcon. Your answer did it for me and works blazingly fast! Will more careful about the cartesian products next time.